# Merge two different dataframes in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

I have two different dataframes, one is date combinations, and one is city pairs:

df_date_combinations:

```
+-------------------+-------------------+
|            fs_date|            ss_date|
+-------------------+-------------------+
|2022-06-01T00:00:00|2022-06-02T00:00:00|
|2022-06-01T00:00:00|2022-06-03T00:00:00|
|2022-06-01T00:00:00|2022-06-04T00:00:00|
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

city pairs:

```
+---------+--------------+---------+--------------+
|fs_origin|fs_destination|ss_origin|ss_destination|
+---------+--------------+---------+--------------+
|      TLV|           NYC|      NYC|           TLV|
|      TLV|           ROM|      ROM|           TLV|
|      TLV|           BER|      BER|           TLV|
+---------+--------------+---------+--------------+
```

I want to combine them so I will have the following dataframe:

```
+----------+----------+---------+--------------+---------+--------------+
|   fs_date|   ss_date|fs_origin|fs_destination|ss_origin|ss_destination|
+----------+----------+---------+--------------+---------+--------------+
|2022-06-01|2022-06-02|      TLV|           NYC|      NYC|           TLV|
|2022-06-01|2022-06-03|      TLV|           NYC|      NYC|           TLV|
|2022-06-01|2022-06-04|      TLV|           NYC|      NYC|           TLV|
|2022-06-01|2022-06-02|      TLV|           ROM|      ROM|           TLV|
|2022-06-01|2022-06-03|      TLV|           ROM|      ROM|           TLV|
|2022-06-01|2022-06-04|      TLV|           ROM|      ROM|           TLV|
|2022-06-01|2022-06-02|      TLV|           BER|      BER|           TLV|
|2022-06-01|2022-06-03|      TLV|           BER|      BER|           TLV|
|2022-06-01|2022-06-04|      TLV|           BER|      BER|           TLV|
+----------+----------+---------+--------------+---------+--------------+
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like a cross join.

```
df1.crossJoin(df2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas actually has built-in methods to do this, we use `concat` to concatenate the dataframes. You can read how to do this here:

- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

The part that is pertinent to you would be:

```
pd.concat([df_date_combinations, city_pairs], axis = 1)
```

Hope this helps!